# Use backslash in knex raw

Tags: node.js, escaping, knex.js

I have a sample code  using knex raw:

```js
let reg = '\((.*?\)'
const result = await knex.raw(`select *, regexp(code, '${reg}', 1,1,null,1) from test ...`);
```

And knex query generate query

```js
select *, regexp(code, '((.*?)', 1,1,null,1) from test ...
```

**->** **Missing backslash**

when I change **reg** variables to
`let reg = '\\((.*?\\)'`

knex query generate :

```sql
select *, regexp(code, '\\((.*?\\)', 1,1,null,1) from test ...
```

**-> Double backslash**

I want my knex query generate query single backslash :

```sql
select *, regexp(code, '\((.*?\)', 1,1,null,1) from test ...
```

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for doesn't make sense. To quote the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html):

> To use a literal instance of a special character in a regular expression, precede it by two backslash (\) characters. The MySQL parser interprets one of the backslashes, and the regular expression library interprets the other. For example, to match the string 1+2 that contains the special + character, only the last of the following regular expressions is the correct one:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('1+2', '1+2');                       -> 0
> mysql> SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('1+2', '1\+2');                      -> 0
> mysql> SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('1+2', '1\\+2');
> ```

So, the double backslash *is* the correct output, the single backslash wouldn't do anything at all.

However you shouldn't even get this output, from a string literal with double backslashes *inserted* into the query (not using a `?` placeholder), so I assume you are misreading the output, it's possibly part of an object or otherwise already again encoded as JS string literal. To get the correct output of double backslashes, you either need to use quadruple backslashes in your string literal or use a parameterized query.

Additionally, your regexp has unbalanced parantheses (one unescaped opening parenthesis but no closing one).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
let reg = '\\((.*?\\)'
const result = await knex.raw(`select *, regexp(code, '?', 1,1,null,1) from test ...`, [reg]);
```

Comment: This isn't logical, the JS string literal `'\((.*?\)' ` will simply evaluate to `((.*?)` and generate a linter error on the way.